# DHTMLX Scheduler conflict with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, dhtmlx, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have some issue connected with bootstrap. I'm trying to divide page on two grids, col-lg6. After I add class to div's I'm getting blank page.

It's my html

```
    <div id="scheduler_here" class="dhx_cal_container" style='width:100%; height:100%;'>
        <div class="dhx_cal_navline">
            <div class="dhx_cal_prev_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_next_button">&nbsp;</div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_today_button"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_date"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="day_tab" style="right:204px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="week_tab" style="right:140px;"></div>
            <div class="dhx_cal_tab" name="month_tab" style="right:76px;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_header"></div>
        <div class="dhx_cal_data"></div>
    </div>


<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    html, body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>
```

and here I have script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    scheduler.init('scheduler_here', new Date(), "week");


    scheduler.form_blocks["my_editor"] = {
        render: function (sns) {
            return "<div class='dhx_cal_ltext' style='height:380px;'>" +
                "<div class='col-lg-6'>" +
                "<p>Nazwa posiłku </p><input type='text' class='form-control'></input>" +
                "<p>Przygotowanie posiłku:</p> <textarea type='text' class='form-control' style='width: 100%;height: 50px; font-size: smaller; line-height: normal'></textarea>" +
                "<br/>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<div class='col-lg-6'>" +
                "<p>Składniki</p>" +
                "<textarea type='text' class='form-control' style='width: 100%;height: 150px; font-size: smaller; line-height: normal;'></textarea>" +
                "</div>" +
                "<p style='margin-left:15px;'>Lista produktów: </p><select class='js-example-basic-single' multiple='multiple' style='width: 98%; margin-left:15px;' id='lightboxCalendar'></select>" +
                "</div><br>";
        },
        set_value: function (node, value, ev) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Calendar/GetDataForInvoiceNumber",
                data: { 'key': '2112sd' },
                type: "post",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    var inner = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                        inner += "<option value='" + data[i].id + "'>" + data[i].Nazwa_Produktu + "</option>";
                    }

                    document.getElementById("lightboxCalendar").innerHTML = inner;                    
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                    alert(err.Message);
                }
            });
            $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
        },
        get_value: function (node, ev) {
            ev.location = node.childNodes[4].value;
            return node.childNodes[1].value;
        },
        focus: function (node) {
            //var a = node.childNodes[1]; s
        }
    }
    scheduler.config.lightbox.sections = [
        { name: "description", height: 500, map_to: "text", type: "my_editor", focus: true }
    ]


    var events = [
{ id: 1, text: "Meeting", start_date: "04/11/2013 14:00", end_date: "04/11/2013 17:00" },
{ id: 2, text: "Conference", start_date: "04/15/2013 12:00", end_date: "04/18/2013 19:00" },
{ id: 3, text: "Interview", start_date: "04/24/2013 09:00", end_date: "04/24/2013 10:00" }
    ];

    scheduler.parse(events, "json");//takes the name and format of the data source
</script>
```

If I create two divs for example

```
<div class='col-lg-6'>---HERE IS CALENDAR---</div>
<div class='col-lg-6'>---WHATEVER</div>
```

My web is blank. Looks like dhtmlx have got some conflicts with bootstrap. Do you have any idea what can be wrong?

Thanks for any help !

Comment: Did you fixe this issue ? could you share ?

Comment: @GregoireMulliez I couldn't fix it so I have switched to full calendar which have almost the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with some help of DHTMLx support
My error was to "forget" to define a size of my div's inside of my grid 
with a couple of col-sm-x (col-sm-3 & col-sm-9) if works like a charm